# Update and Display state prams on state chage

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have some items that I would like to update when the state is changed but I am unsure as to how I can get this working using `ui-router`.

I have added title,mainClass,headerSearch to the state (see below) and I would like to access these when the stateChange is successful. so I may have something like `class="{{ $state.curent.title }}"` which would inherit `title` when the state is changed, so if home state was active it would look like `class="home"`

This is how I have attempted to set thing up (I was using `ng-router` where I had a similar set up that worked perfectly).

State Controller:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('cbuiRouterApp')
  .config(function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('main', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'app/main/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl',
        title: 'Home',
        mainClass: 'home',
        headerSearch: null
      });
  });
```

State Change:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, current){
  // Assign site Title
  $rootScope.siteName = 'ChoppingBlock';
  //Change Page name
  $rootScope.title = current.$$route.title;
  // Add page class to <body>
  $rootScope.mainClass = current.$$route.mainClass;
  // add header navigation
  $rootScope.headerSearch = current.$$route.headerSearch;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could

```
app.run(['$rootScope', '$state', function ($rootScope, $state){
     $rootScope.$state = $state;
}]);
```

and after that it's possible to `class="{{ $state.current.title }}"` or `$scope.$state.current.title` in any controller.

Comment: Legend! Cheers for that, worked like a charm, I had actually seen this https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/master/sample/app/app.js but I think I must have implemented it incorectly.